Issue with multiple instances of using SVG FIlter to round the clip paths
I am trying to use SVG Filters to create rounded clipping paths overs an image as described in this blog post: "How to make rounded corners when using css clip path polygon".

For this reason here is the html code
<div class="box_parent">
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <svg class="flt_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <filter id="flt_tag">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="flt_tag" />
                <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="flt_tag" operator="atop"/>
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</div>

and the accompanying CSS for it
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .box2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("image1url");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #faebd7;
    clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, 77% 0%, 77% 44%, 100% 44%, 100% 100%, 81% 100%, 81% 72%, 0 73%);
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
.flt_svg {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

.box_parent {
  filter: url("#flt_tag");
}

My scenario is, I am going to create multiple of these on a single page but if I duplicate withput changing the class names and only changing IMAGE_URL, both boxes show same image.
If I change the classnames to make it entirely different thing, there is no output
I tried giving different class names to each reference of class names i-e
<div class="3box_parent">
    <div class="box3"></div>

    <svg class="3flt_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <filter id="3flt_tag">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="flt_tag" />
                <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="3flt_tag" operator="atop"/>
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>

</div>

and then in the css as this
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .3box2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("image2url");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #faebd7;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 77% 0%, 77% 44%, 100% 44%, 100% 100%, 81% 100%, 81% 72%, 0 73%);
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .3flt_svg {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
}

.3box_parent {
  filter: url("#3flt_tag");
}  


Better avoid class names or IDs starting with numbers
From the W3C Specs

In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
(_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B&W?" or "B\26 W\3F".

they can work with some escaping: but you should rather opt for suffixes like box-i
Besides you only need to define the SVG corner rounding filter (also referred to as "goo/gooey filter") once – make sure the filter IDs is not used by other inlined SVG assets.


/* actually not neeeded as the SVG doesn't contain any rendered elements */
.flt_svg {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

/* apply "goo" filter for rounded corners */
.box_parent {
    filter: url("#flt_tag");
}


.clipped {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    77% 0%,
    77% 44%,
    100% 44%,
    100% 100%,
    81% 100%,
    81% 72%,
    0 73%
  );
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* image 1 */
.box1{
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/1000/1000");
}

/* image 2 */
.box2{
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/238/1000/1000");
}

/* image 3 */
.box3{
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/235/1000/1000");
}
<div class="box_parent">
  <div class="clipped box1"></div>
  <div class="clipped box2"></div>
  <div class="clipped box3"></div>
</div>

<!-- define ronded cornder filter -->
<svg class="flt_svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="flt_tag">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="flt_tag" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="flt_tag" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>



Keep in mind a background-image doesn't have intrinsic dimensions:
In the above example I've added an implicit height via aspect-ratio. You could as well specify both width and height properties.
Frankly, you should using consider <img> elements instead to get more features like alt attributes for better accessibility or srcset abilities for responsive images.


.img-clipped {
  width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    77% 0%,
    77% 44%,
    100% 44%,
    100% 100%,
    81% 100%,
    81% 72%,
    0 73%
  );
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* round-clip */
.clip-rounded{
  filter: url("#flt_tag");
}
<div class="clip-rounded">
  <img class="img-clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/1200/1200" alt="image">
</div>

<div class="clip-rounded">
  <img class="img-clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/236/1600/900" alt="image">
</div>

<div class="clip-rounded">
  <img class="img-clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/234/2400/900" alt="image">
</div>

<!-- define ronded corner filter -->
<svg class="flt_svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="flt_tag">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="flt_tag" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="flt_tag" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>



However we also need a wrapping element to apply the SVG corner-rounding filter.
Further reading

"goo filter"

